# Permutation matrix preseves volume of a set in Euclidean space

Tags: metric-spaces, permutations, volume, isometry

Suppose I have a set $U$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$. For example, $[3,5]$ in $\mathbb{R}$. We know that the volume (length) in this example is $2$.

Suppose I have a permutation matrix $P$, I want to show the volume: $\mbox{vol}(U) = \mbox{vol}(PU)$. $PU $ means permuting each point in $U$. Here the permutation means $$\begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3 \end{bmatrix} \rightarrow \begin{bmatrix} x_2 \\ x_1 \\ x_3 \end{bmatrix}. $$

It seems trivial because $|P| = \pm1$, it is an isometry and entries of $P$ are $1$ and $0$. So permutation matrices preserve volume.

However, is there any way to strictly prove it?

Comment: That the determinant is $\pm 1$ is quite a strict way, I would think.

Comment: You don't even need the determinant -- it's true simply by symmetry.